# What is "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+" or "com.android.support:leanback-v17:+"? What's the relationship and difference between them?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have to add `compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:+'` to my `build.gradle` every time I new an android project in IntelliJ IDEA.However, my configuration has included `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'`, they seem to be both support packages.What are the relationships and differences between them?

Comment: Leanback is for Android TV and AppCompat is for compatibility support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both Android Support APIs from Google.

**Android App Compat API:**

> v7 appcompat library
>
> This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design
>   pattern. This library includes support for material design user
>   interface implementations.

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7

**Android Lean Back API:**

> The android.support.v17.leanback package provides APIs to support
>   building user interfaces on TV devices. It provides a number of
>   important widgets for TV apps. Some of the notable classes include:

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback

Comment: Thanks.According to your answer, I find my problem.In IntelliJ IDEA, the default `Activity` is `Android TV Activity`.I am new andorid programmer, so I just ignore choice.